# Stuck on Mathematical Induction Proof

Tags: induction

I have the following question: Prove with mathematical induction that $3^n+4^n\le 5^n$ for all $n\ge 2$.
$$\text{Assume true: }3^n+4^n \le 5^n \text{. Prove that $3^{n+1}+4^{n+1} \le 5^{n+1}$} \\
= 3\cdot3^n+4\cdot4^n \\ =3\cdot3^n+4^n(3+1)\\
=3\cdot3^n+3\cdot4^n+4^n \\ 
=3(3^n+4^n)+4^n \\
\le 3(5^n)+4^n \\
(5-2)(5^n)+4^n \\
5^{n+1} - 2\cdot5^n+4^n\\
5^{n+1} - 2\cdot(3^n+4^n) +4^n$$
I am stuck on. I see now that I double the $5^n$, and this leads me nowhere. Where can I go from here to solve this? I have tried playing with the algebra, but I am not getting anywhere with this last step.

Comment: You are almost there. Since $4\le 5$, $4^n\le 5^n$, and in the middle there you have $3\cdot 5^n+4^n<3\cdot 5^n+5^n=4\cdot 5^n<5^{n+1}$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this, with the same first step:
$$\begin{align*}
3^{n+1} + 4^{n+1} &\le 3 \cdot 3^n + 4 \cdot 4^n \\
         &\le 5 \cdot 3^n + 5 \cdot 4^n \\
         &\le 5(3^n + 4^n) \\
         &\le 5 \cdot 5^n \\ &= 5^{n+1}
\end{align*}
$$

Comment: Wow, I totally missed that. Elegant.

Comment: I should of stated that I assumed $3^n+4^n \le 5^n$ is true for all $n\ge 2$. I don't know if I could use this with my assumption.

Comment: That's not how induction works. You cannot *assume* that $3^n + 4^n \le 5^n$ is true for all $n \ge 2$ because that's what you are trying to *prove*. Instead, you first do the basis step, proving that $3^n + 4^n \le 5^n$ is true for $n=2$. Then you do the induction step, by proving that the following **implication** is true for all $n$: $$\text{If $3^n + 4^n \le 5^n$ then $3^{n+1} + 4^{n+1} \le 5^{n+1}$}$$ Which is what my answer does.

Comment: Oh nice! I don't fully understand induction as you can see. Very nice!

Answer (score 1):

From where you left off, we have
$$
5^{n+1}-2(3^n+4^n)+4^n=5^{n+1}-2\cdot3^n - 4^n\leq 5^{n+1}
$$
and your proof is finished.